# Is it possible to iterate a masked enum in objective c

Tags: objective-c, enums, iteration

I've seen that this is possible in other languages but need something like this in objective-c

I have an enum similar to this

```
typedef enum {
  option1 = 1 << 0,
  option2 = 1 << 1,
  option3 = 1 << 2
...
...
} SomePossibleOptions;
```

and then a user can create a mask of the wanted options

```
SomePossibleOptions myOptions = option1 | option2;

[self.someObject performOperationsForOptions:myOptions];

-(void)performOperationsForOptions:(SomePossibleOptions)theOptions
{

if (myOptions & option1)
{
  // do something
}

if (myOptions & option2
{
 // do something
}

//(could use a switch statement)

}
```

But would much rather use some sort of syntax

```
foreach (option in myoption)
{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: This is not possible because at run time, there's no longer an enumeration of values... just a bunch of integers. `enum` is a compile time convenience only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes I use a last value in my normal enums called "SomeEnumCount", which then has exactly the number of items I have in the enum, so I can make a loop for that.

In your case it would be something like this:

```
typedef enum {
  option1 = 1 << 0,
  option2 = 1 << 1,
  option3 = 1 << 2,
...
...
  optionCount = 1 << n
} SomePossibleOptions;
```

Or maybe you can call it OptionNone, if you have one like that, and that would be always the last one.

And to make a loop you have to make something like this

```
NSInteger optionsCount = (int)log2(optionCount);
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < optionsCount; i++) {
    SomePossibleOptions option = (SomePossibleOptions)(1 << i);

    //handle your options here
}
```

I hope it helps!

EDIT: Maybe I misunderstood the question. If you want to loop on just the options that are masked together, you should write a function, based on the above. Something like:

```
- (NSArray *)optionsInMask:(SomePossibleOptions)maskedOptions {
    NSMutableArray * options = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSInteger optionsCount = (int)log2(optionCount);
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < optionsCount; i++) {
        SomePossibleOptions option = (SomePossibleOptions)(1 << i);
        if (maskedOptions & option) {
            [options addObject:[NSValue valueWithInteger:option]];
        }
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:options];
}
```

And then you can loop it like:

```
for (NSValue * value in [self optionsInMask:myOptions]) {
    SomePossibleOption option = (SomePossibleOptions)[value integerValue];

    //your code here
}
```